# R - list of list - select id of unempty list

Tags: r, list, for-loop

I try some searching and data analyze in R. I have code like this :

```
data = matrix( 
  c(3, 21, 80, 208,
    3, 49, 80, 1298,
    5, 17, 80, 302,
    8, 28, 80, 2857,
    13, 08, 80, 2860,
    14, 08, 80, 2860,
    15, 58, 80, 208,
    15, 58, 80, 463,
    15, 58, 80, 2065,
    15, 58, 80, 2065,
    13, 05, 80, 608,
    13, 08, 80, 608
     ), 

  nrow=12,             
  ncol=4,              
  byrow = TRUE)        

#find a match with numbers 13 and 8 in column 1
require(AhoCorasickTrie)
keywords = c("13","8 ")
SearchNew = AhoCorasickSearch(keywords,data[,1])
```

And SearchNew look like that :

```
> SearchNew
[[1]]
list()

[[2]]
list()

[[3]]
list()

[[4]]
list()

[[5]]
[[5]][[1]]
[[5]][[1]]$Keyword
[1] "13"

[[5]][[1]]$Offset
[1] 1

[[6]]
list()

[[7]]
list()

[[8]]
list()

[[9]]
list()

[[10]]
list()

[[11]]
[[11]][[1]]
[[11]][[1]]$Keyword
[1] "13"

[[11]][[1]]$Offset
[1] 1

[[12]]
[[12]][[1]]
[[12]][[1]]$Keyword
[1] "13"

[[12]][[1]]$Offset
[1] 1
```

What I want are indexes of rows where lists are not empty. That mean in this case it will be 5, 11, 12. I try to do this :

```
xyz <- vector('list', length(SearchNew))
for(i in seq_along(SearchNew)){
  for(j in seq_along(SearchNew[[i]])){
    if (length(SearchNew[[i]]) > 0)
      xyz <- i 
  }
}
```

But this give me matrix with lots of NULL rows. And I cant give xyz just 3 rows because I don't know have many nonempty rows will be in list.  I am new in R so I don't have any idea how to solve this. Any help ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `lengths` to find the index of elements that have non-zero `length`

```
which(lengths(SearchNew)!=0)
#[1]  5 11 12
```

If we need to subset those elements, use `Filter`

```
Filter(length, SearchNew)
```